# Google Spreadsheet, the first column is the one selected by script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can I select a cell in a Google spreadsheet and show it as the first column on the left? I'll explain. I have a spreadsheet and through a script, point to a specific column. I would like this column to be the first one that appears to the left of the screen.
Thank you

Current situation:

[image: Current situation]

How I want it to be:

[image: how I want it to be]

Comment: Please provide further details, include your script so far, and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Until now I can select a cell according to a date and a name. For example, today is Tuesday, December 18, 2018, the script allows me to position myself on the column that identifies the date 18 December. The script reads the user with which you are connected and is positioned on the line of your name. The row column meeting is your cell of the day. The scipt does not do anything else. What I would like to do is show the first column on the left, the one selected.

Comment: Please include your script in your question. Please also include a screenshot. I am finding it difficult to understand your explanation.

Comment: I put the pictures, I hope it's a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I see what you mean. Unfortunately, I don't know of a documented way to position the sheet like that.

However, you could use `range.activate()` twice--once to select the whole range that needs to be visible (will cause the sheet to centre over the selected range), then again to select the single cell. For example, if your screen displays 10 columns and 20 rows, you would choose use something like: `yourSelectedCell.offset(0, 0, 20, 10).activate();`

This will select a range that is 20 rows high and 10 columns wide from your start cell.

You will have to play with the number of rows and columns.

Comment: Hello. I tried your solution, but this only allows me to select, but I do not move the screen. Other solutions? Thanks

Comment: The range that you selected, was it just big enough to select the whole visible range? Please screenshot whole screen while range is selected. :)